# ¿Cómo puedo limitar el tamaño de las líneas dentro de un jTextArea?

Tags: java, java-swing, salto-de-linea

Quiero poder hacer un salto de línea cuando dentro del jTextArea se este escribiendo y no alcance una palabra dentro la línea de este, la ultima palabra que quedo a medias se pase a la siguiente línea.

Lo que pensaba era contar los caracteres pero la longitud de una línea no depende solamente de la cantidad de caracteres, también del tipo de fuente y su tamaño (así que podría usar una fuente y tamaño de letra fijo pero no es la idea).

Busque en paginas pero solo encontré sobre limitar caracteres pero para el jTextField.

*Me fije que este mismo cuadro de texto en el que estoy escribiendo tiene esta propiedad de que cuando una palabra llega al limite del cuadro pasa a la siguiente línea, jejeje*

No pongo código porque no he intentado nada que funcione, no soy nada experto en Java, pensaba en usar el keyTyped pero seria lo mismo de limitar caracteres que no funciona para todo tipo de fuente, desconozco si existe alguna propiedad que solucione esto, por favor si podrían ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad es mucho más sencillo, Swing [ya lo hace por ti](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap(boolean)):

```
myJTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me solucionaste muchos códigos :3